# Please can we document how tags and wild cards interact in the help center?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, help-center, help-center-proposed

While writing [this question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12148/how-to-find-non-dd-related-questions) I noticed we don't actually document how tags and wildcards interact.

As per the [help pages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/searching) we document them separately:

> To search within specific tag(s), enter them in square brackets: [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance) seat searches for mentions of "seat" within the [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance) tag.

> Use wildcard searches to broaden results; add an asterisk (*) anywhere in the word, like encour* or Ex*nge.

It's not too bad, but because the wild cards get expanded, you need to constantly re-enter them in the non-expanded form.

Can we please document this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @OrangeDog try searching for `[help-center*]`

Comment: I see. But why do you have to constantly re-enter them? It seems to work just fine.

Comment: @OrangeDog If you [search for `[status-*]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-*), your search term (and the search URL) gets converted to the expanded form `[status-completed] or [status-bydesign] or [status-declined] or [status-norepro] or [status-deferred] or [status-review] or [status-planned] or [status-reproduced]`. That makes adjusting your terms for subsequent searches, at the very least, a little more annoying.